# The fundamental group of a plane without a finite number of points.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> How can I calculate de fundamenta group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ without a finite number of points?

I know that the answer should be $S^1\vee S^1 \vee \cdots \vee S^1 $ where the product repeats as many as points removed.

Thanks for helps!

Comment: [Deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract)?

Comment: I know, but it is not easy to choose some way to show it explicity.

Comment: I is already, edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a proof by induction that the group is free of rank~$n$ where $n$ points have been removed. The induction step uses Van Kampen's theorem. Letting the points be $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, there exists a line $L$ disjoint from $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that each component of $\mathbb{R}^2-L$ contains at least one of the points. Renumber the points so that $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are in one side and $x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n$ are on the other. By induction, the first side has fundamental group $F_k$ (the free group of rank $k$) and the other has fundamental group $F_{n-k}$. By Van Kampen's theorem, the fundamental group of the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n-\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is the free product of $F_k$ and $F_{n-k}$ which is $F_n$.

Comment: Wonderful! This proof avoid every type of complication (or intuition) as deformation retracts. Thanks!

Comment: Take lines on either side of $L$, parallel to it, and very close. $U$ is a half plane bounded one of of those lines, $V$ a half plane bounded by the other. The intersection is a narrow strip centered on $L$, which is simply connected.

Comment: But when you invoke with induction hypothesis, that $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{k-points\}$ has fundamental group of a wedge of $k$ circles, we are really looking at half a plane with boundary (the line L), so is it technically correct to use the induction hypothesis? The induction hypothesis I assume would be that if $k \leq n$ then the fundamental group of the plane minus $k$ points the same as a wedge of $k$ circles.

Comment: No, the induction hypothesis is that my first sentence is true for $n$ replaced by any value $1 \le k \le n-1$. Deformation retractions have nothing to do with this particular method.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've got two questions : What could it be a way to define "explicitly" such $L$? And second, how do you prove that those are open set in order to apply van Kampen correctly ?