# Let $S$ be containing $n$ distinct points of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then prove $\mathbb{R}^{2}-S \simeq \vee_{i=1}^{n}S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

In order to solve the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ minus $n$ distinct points i stumbled across the following problem :

I'd have liked to create the following homopoty equivalence between $S^{1}$ and just $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ minus a point $w$ and then iterate the process :

$$\mathbb{R}^{2}-w \overset{r}{\longmapsto} S^{1} \overset{i}{\longmapsto} \mathbb{R}^{2}-w$$

Such that $r(v) =\frac{v-w}{\|v-w\|_{2}}$ and $i(v) =\frac{v-w}{\|v-w\|_{2}} +w$  for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^{2}-w$.

And then define $H : (\mathbb{R}^{2}-w) \times [0,1] \longmapsto (\mathbb{R}^{2}-w)$ such that $H(v,t) = (1-t)(\frac{v-w}{\|v-w\|_{2}} + w)+tv$.

The problem however is that the map is not well defined since there are values of $t$ for which $(1-t)(\frac{v-w}{\|v-w\|_{2}} + w)+tv = w$.

What am I missing here ? Another approach I tried is : given the $n$ points define $n$ disjoint balls around them and try something as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186956/prove-that-mathbb-r-n-without-a-finite-number-of-points-is-simply-connected) but I was unable to show that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ minus these points retracts onto the boundary of these balls.

The problem has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329562/the-fundamental-group-of-a-plane-without-a-finite-number-of-points) as well without direct proof, I think the more accurate proof and similar to my idea is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260290/fundamental-group-of-the-complement-of-k-points-in-mathbbr2). However, instead of simply understand the solution given I'd like to understand the problem in mine in order to comprehend what is wrong, which is why opened the question.

Comment: There isn't any such $t$.

Comment: @JWL This reassures me if mine was a calculus error, is this approach right? Could you give me some hint on the retraction on the boundary of the balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a little mistake in the definition of $H(v,t)$.

Consider the stadard retraction from $\mathbb R^2 \ \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ to $S^1$ given by:
$$
F:\mathbb R^2 \ \backslash \{(0,0)\}\times [0,1] \rightarrow S^1\subset \mathbb R^2 \ \backslash \{(0,0)\}, \quad F(v,t) = \frac{v}{||v||}(1-t) + tv
$$

The map you are looking for is 
$$H:\mathbb R^2 \ \backslash \{w\}\times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \ \backslash \{w\}, \quad H(v,t) = \tau_w \circ F_t \circ \tau_{-w}(v)$$
where $\tau_w$ is the traslation by the vector $w$: $\tau_w(v) = v+w$. The idea is to translate the problem in the origin, resolve it and come back.

If you expand the formula you obtain:
$$
H(v,t) = \frac{v-w}{||v-w||}(1-t) + (v-w)t + w
$$